# Very simple ssis script transformation giving Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I have an ssis package that takes a flat file and dumps it to SQL.  During that process, 150 columns need to have '-' and '.' removed from them.  I have done this using a Script Transformation.

```
    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    Dim column As IDTSInputColumn90
    Dim rowType As Type = Row.GetType()
    Dim columnValue As PropertyInfo

    For Each column In Me.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection(0).InputColumnCollection

        columnValue = rowType.GetProperty(column.Name)

        Dim strCol As String = columnValue.GetValue(Row, Nothing).ToString()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strCol) Then
            strCol = strCol.Replace("-", "").Replace(".", "")
            columnValue.SetValue(Row, strCol, Nothing)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I however get the following error when running it

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
at ScriptComponent_f20c21e11e3348378ef0bbe6b65e9c05.ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
at ScriptComponent_f20c21e11e3348378ef0bbe6b65e9c05.UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
at ScriptComponent_f20c21e11e3348378ef0bbe6b65e9c05.UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, PipelineBuffer Buffer)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
```

I can't figure out why this is happening.. Any thoughts?

**Edit** I've discovered that this line is the problem

```
Dim strCol As String = columnValue.GetValue(Row, Nothing).ToString()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: Not really. I understand NullRefExceptions.. but in this case I can't see it or figure out how to avoid it.. I've tried pre defining strCol as "bob", but I believe setting it to the GetValue of the column is causing the grief.. I can't figure out how to get around it

Comment: How to get around it? Something is set to `Nothing`. Find out what it is, then fix that.

Comment: I'm reading from a flat file.. some of the fields are blank.. I know this, but I don't know how to precheck if the field is blank before I try to assign it to my string

Comment: SSIS 2008 or 2005? I assume 2005 based on the reference to `IDTSInputColumn90` but just like to cover the bases.

Comment: Not blank. `Nothing` is a totally different concept.

Comment: Well in my flat file which is a csv, it goes ,,,,,,,,, for a section.  I assume that vb is reading that as Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work for my dataset. I skipped the cast to string type and just left it as object type [based on what I assume to be the source of your script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214510/ssis-script-component-to-remove-0-charachers-in-charn-fields). It's not pretty but it seems to get the job done.

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    Dim column As IDTSInputColumn90
    Dim rowType As Type = Row.GetType()
    Dim columnValue As PropertyInfo

    For Each column In Me.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection(0).InputColumnCollection

        columnValue = rowType.GetProperty(column.Name)
        Dim meta As Integer = column.ExternalMetadataColumnID
        Try
            Dim Obj As Object = columnValue.GetValue(Row, Nothing)
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Obj) Then
                Obj = Obj.Replace("-", "").Replace(".", "")
                columnValue.SetValue(Row, Obj.ToString(), Nothing)
            End If
        Finally
            ' Rejoice in our null-ness
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

### Source data

Starting with this data

```
SourceSSN,DestinationSSN,Amount
,111-11-0000,5000.00
111-22-3333,111-22-3334,5000.00
121-22-3333,121-22-3334,5000.00
123-22-3333,123-22-3334,5000.00
124-22-3333,124-22-3334,5000.00
```

The above script makes this

[image]

Comment: Dim Obj As Object = columnValue.GetValue(Row, Nothing) still throws the reference error

Comment: If you define a simple file with the source data provided, does it work?

Comment: Also, if you have the try block, you should not get an error thrown